# How to store a file in a mysql database using blob

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I have searched about this matter a lot but, I didn't get a proper solution for my problem, I have following method for storing a file using java,

```
private void uploadFile() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/FileDb?autoReconnect=true", "user1", "123789");
        System.out.println("DB connection extablished!");

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO FilesTb(`FileData`) VAULES(?)");

        File file = new File(txtDir.getText() + "/" + txtFile.getText());// get path and file name from text fields

        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        statement.setBlob(1, fIn);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File stored successfully!");

    }
```

when I try to run this code I got following error,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VAULES(_binary'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<jasperReport xmlns=\"' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2398)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2316)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2301)
        at com.views.FileUploader.uploadFile(FileUploader.java:154)
        at com.views.FileUploader.btnUploadActionPerformed(FileUploader.java:125)
        at com.views.FileUploader.access$100(FileUploader.java:27)
        at com.views.FileUploader$2.actionPerformed(FileUploader.java:66)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

please assist me regarding this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert the file data into byte array and set in the sql statement

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
File fBlob = new File ("<your_path>");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fBlob);
statement.setBinaryStream(1, is, (int) fBlob.length());
statement.execute();
```