# Java File type into SQL Insert clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql, file

I ran into an awkward problem.

I need to insert some values into an SQL table.

For that i use an `Insert` clause, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `USERS`(`ID`, `FILE`, `PROPERTIES`) VALUES ('1', FILE, '{"attributes":{"LANGUAGE":"ENG","AUTHOR":"John"}}')
```

My problem is the `File` value. I don't know how i can insert a `File` object in these circumstances. And since i cannot pass the value `NULL`, due to program restrictions, how can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a file in a mysql database using blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476434/how-to-store-a-file-in-a-mysql-database-using-blob)

Comment: @Barett i don't see how this is a duplicate! It's a completely different question... just about the same topic

Comment: I disagree (the answer given there is exactly the answer to your question), but I will help a little more if that isn't enough information for you. What persistence library are you using: JPA, JDBC, other?

Comment: I'm using a `dbinit.sql` file to do the inserts before running the application. i'm using a JDBC connection pool, but that doesn't matter here. i just want to know how i can insert a File object into a SQL table @Barett

Comment: How you're executing your query does matter. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most persistence libraries won't let you do this directly. (none that I'm aware of)

1. convert the file into a byte array using [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) or an equivalent
2. (if using JDBC) call [`PreparedStatement.setBytes(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes(int,%20byte[])) to pass this value to the database

Alternative solution: put the actual file in some known disk location and store only the filename/path in the database.